# why the component is getting unmounted and mounter everytime when the state is changed

Tags: reactjs, redux, components, render

Home.JS

```
class Home extends Component{

state = {
    serverPosts:null,
    offlinePosts:[],
    isLoading:false,
    isError:false,
    error:null
}

componentDidMount(){
    console.log("home did mount")
    this.setState({isLoading:true})
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then((response)=>{
            this.setState({
                serverPosts:response.data,
                isLoading:false
            })
        }).catch((err)=>{
            this.setState({
                isError:true,
                error:err
            })
        })
}

addOfflinePost = (post) => {
    const offlineList = [...this.state.offlinePosts,{post}]
    this.setState({offlinePosts:offlineList})
}


render(){
    console.log("Home component render")
    let serverPostList = (this.state.serverPosts)?
        this.state.serverPosts.map((item,index)=>{ return <Post postData = {item} key={index}/>}):
            (this.state.isError)?<p>No Internet Connection</p>:<p>No Post available</p>

    let offlinePostList = (this.state.offlinePosts)?
this.state.offlinePosts.map((item, index)=>{ return <Post postData = {item} key={`id-${index}`}/>}):<button className="btn btn-primary mx-auto" onClick={this.mainContentHandler}>Add Post</button>;
   

    return(
            <div className={classes.Home}>
                <div className="row py-2">
                    <div className="col-lg-4">  
                        <div className={"row "+ classes.OfflineList}>
                        </div>
                        <div className={"row "+ classes.ServerList}>
                            {serverPostList}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-8">
                            <PostForm click = {this.addOfflinePost}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    )
}
}

export default Home;
```

AddForm.JS

```
class PostForm extends Component{

state = {
    title:null,
    content:null
}

titleChangeHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({title:event.target.value})
}

contentChangeHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({content:event.target.value})
}


render(){
    return (
    <div className="card card-primary">
        <div className="card-header">
            POST
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title" onChange={this.titleChangeHandler}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Content" onChange={this.contentChangeHandler}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick={()=>this.props.click(this.state)}>Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
)}
}

export default PostForm;
```

Q1. The render function is running multiple times when the component get loaded. When i submit the form then the componentDidMount is running everytime. Please explain me how the flow is working in this component.

Q2. Also if you help me with the best practice of using bootstrap and manual styling together in react

Comment: why did you re-edit the post?

Comment: @apostolos names of JS files were wrong

Comment: @Apostolos can you help me with this

Comment: it doesnt make sense. componentDidMount should not run all the time. componentDidUpdate should do that, if applicable.

Comment: @Apostolos that's what i am trying to find